# How to add more Applications on a single App Engine user account

Tags: google-app-engine

I have alot of small application back ends and websites running on app engine. I have reached the maximum of 12 apps. I was wondering if there is a way to add more to a single user? Why is the limit 12? Is there a future version of GAE which lets user create more applications? Can i pay to have more on a single user account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I'm not sure if you can pay to get more, you can have 10 more from your Google Apps account if you have one. You can then add your personal account in the admins of that app and continue normally.

While this smells like a workaround, it actually make sense, since eventually you are going to deploy your app on it's own domain and you will need to have a Google Apps account in order to achieve that. From there if you have more users for a particular domain, each of them can start up to 10 apps, which of course you (they) can share with more people, so in theory there is no limit :)

You can create a [Google Apps account](http://www.google.com/enterprise/apps/business/) by starting a free trial and after 30 days you can downgrade to a free version if you have only one user. If you have more then you will have to start paying for it (unfortunatelly that was changed recently).